# Can't start emacs, but I installed it with Homebrew

Tags: emacs, macos-sierra

When I start emacs with "emacs", i get "-bash: /usr/bin/emacs: No such file or directory". But I installed it with "brew install emacs".
I know emacs is installed, cause it is there when I do "brew list".

I can install the GUI version, but I want to use it in Terminal. How can I do that?

I'm on macOS Sierra.
I did "brew update" several times.

Thanks.

Comment: `I can install the GUI version`. How do you use the GUI version? By clicking its icon?

Comment: Yes. I installed it with Brew. And then I Had an Icon

Comment: Try `open -a /Applications/Emacs.app`. Does this command start an emacs?

Comment: Open -a applications/emacs.app works. Opens The Gui Version

Comment: `open -a /Applications/Emacs.app -nw` will run emacs in terminal.

Comment: No that doesnt Work. "Unrecognized Option"

Comment: i get the same error again

Comment: Weird. What about `brew linkapps emacs`?

Comment: i got this: Unfortunately `brew linkapps` cannot behave nicely with e.g. Spotlight using
either aliases or symlinks and Homebrew formulae do not build "proper" `.app`
bundles that can be relocated. Instead, please consider using `brew cask` and
migrate formulae using `.app`s to casks.

Comment: So maybe you should try to reinstall with `brew cask install emacs`?

Comment: I get The Same Problems

Comment: So it installs. An i can start The GUI. But Not in The terminal

Comment: `emacs --no-window`?

Comment: "Unrecognized Option". I also tried "Open -a applications/emacs.app --no-window

Comment: Oh im sry when i do Just Emacs --no-window iget "no such File or..."

Comment: This is too weird. I've just installed emacs on another OSX laptop and use `emacs -nw` and everything goes fine. There must be some magic on your computer. I'll delete my answer. Sorry for not providing anything helpful :(

Comment: No Problem. I'll try updating to high Sierra. Maybe that works

Comment: I can only upvote your question to make more people look at it :joy:

Comment: Thanks ;) do you know a different way to install Emacs?(Not using Brew)

Comment: No, my laptop is Ubuntu Linux. The OSX laptop mentioned above is my girlfrend's :)

Comment: Okay thank you for your help

Comment: Something is clearly interested in the path `/usr/bin/emacs`. Is that where the ancient version 22 of Emacs that OSX includes is installed? What does `which emacs` return? What about `alias emacs`?

Comment: The old Version is not on my mac anymore. Which Emacs Returns /usr/local/bin/emacs. An If i execute /usr/local/bin/emacs The GUI Version starts

Comment: And what about my last question? Does `alias emacs` show anything? (At this point it sounds extremely like it.)

Comment: alias: emacs: Not found. But for some reason The Emacs GUI starts now when i Type in emacs. And with emacs -nw it Starts in The terminal. So The Problem is solved.(although i dont know why)